# Problems getting Foundation 4 JS to work in WP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm merging [Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/) with [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/) to create a WP Starter theme. I had everything working fine with the JS from Foundation 3, but now that I'm trying to implement the Foundation 4 JS I'm running into some issues.

I followed the steps found in the [Foundation 4 JS Documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html), but still had no luck. Here is the code I placed directly before the closing body tag (I know the correct way is to enqueue the script, but for testing I was just pasting it directly above the closing body tag):

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=http://mcfaddengavender.net/jeremy/wp-content/themes/bones-master/library/js/vendor/'
+ ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
+ '.js><\/script>');
</script>   

<script src="http://mcfaddengavender.net/jeremy/wp-content/themes/bones-master/library/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
```

I'm attempting to open a modal on [this page](http://mcfaddengavender.net/jeremy/?page_id=2#), but as you can see, the modal never fires when you click the link. I notice some errors in the Javascript console, but I'm still new to JS so they are a bit over my head.

As I mentioned before, things were working fine with the Foundation 3 JS, which didn't require the call to initialize the function - it just seemed to work. Not sure if that makes a huge difference, but it's something I noticed that was different about the documentation for Foundation 4 JS compared to Foundation 3 JS.

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the browser can't find Zepto (at least chrome can't).

It's looking for it here:
http://mcfaddengavender.net/library/js/vendor/zepto.js but it returns a 404

Make sure you have your libraries set up in the appropriate directories!

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I added in absolute links and I'm still having some issues. However, there are less errors in the Error Console. I edited the original post with the new code.

Comment: Hmmm that's strange.  I'm not sure why this is happening, but I see you are loading jquery 1.8.3 further up in the html, maybe try removing that and placing the document.write up before your other js file declarations?

Comment: I removed the extra call to jQuery and even tried moving the code up into the header, still no luck. (So I moved everything back to the footer for the purposes of figuring this out). I really appreciate your help though - we went from having 8-9 errors to about 3, so we're getting closer! : )

Comment: i'm having a similar issue here loading foundation4 js into my custom application - 0 errors in the console so go figure. did you ever get this work?

Answer (score 0):

well after i commented, i got it to work lol.  maybe this will help you or someone else.

it seems like the docs are a little bit confusing, i was only able to get plugin functionality from loading foundation/foundation.js and foundation-whatever-plugin.js in this sequence - loading just foundation.js did not work for me.

i'm using requirejs to load so i don't have to worry about paths, but for your purposes just make sure you're not having any paths issue and this load order should work. for troubleshooting purposes i'm bypassing modernizr / zepto detectors and just loading jquery straight.

```
 requirejs.config({

 baseUrl: "/path/to/scripts",
 paths:{
  jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min',
 },
 shim: {

    'foundation/foundation': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.alerts': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.clearing': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.cookie': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.dropdown': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.forms': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.joyride': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.magellan': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.orbit': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.placeholder': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.reveal': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.section': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.tooltips': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'foundation/foundation.topbar': { deps: ['jquery'] },
    'vendor/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput.min': { deps: ['jquery']},
    'vendor/chosen/chosen/chosen.jquery': { deps: ['jquery']},
    'vendor/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.min': { deps: ['jquery']},
    'vendor/tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min': {
      deps: [
      'jquery', 
      'vendor/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.min'
      ]
    },
    'vendor/redactor-js/redactor/redactor.min': { deps: ['jquery']},
    'lib/jquery.passwordstrength': { deps: ['jquery']}
```

}

});

```
require(["jquery",
"foundation/foundation",
"foundation/foundation.alerts",
"foundation/foundation.clearing",
"foundation/foundation.cookie",
"foundation/foundation.dropdown",
"foundation/foundation.forms",
"foundation/foundation.joyride",
"foundation/foundation.magellan",
"foundation/foundation.orbit",
"foundation/foundation.placeholder",
"foundation/foundation.reveal",
"foundation/foundation.section",
"foundation/foundation.tooltips",
"foundation/foundation.topbar"
], function ($) {
  $(document).foundation();
});
```