# Add javascript to Foundation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I have installed the Foundation 4 gem but now I would like to add some javascript such as dropdown buttons. I followed the instructions but zepto, jquery and foundation.min.js are not loaded when I get a view ("No route matches")

I added in the application layout :

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
 <script src="/js/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

in the head

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "js/vendor/custom.modernizr" %>
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>
<script src="js/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

at the end of the body.

But there is no folder js/vendor right ? Where must I put them ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you place JavaScript in your vendor folder, you can include it in your Rails application by adding it to your `application.js`file.

sample **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= custom.modernizr
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
```

Sprockets will look in your various assets directories to find your JavaScript.

Comment: Still does not work... However if I pick up the code from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180310/problems-getting-foundation-4-js-to-work-in-wp I get the dropdown but not at the place it should be

Comment: I think it is not loaded. Indeed in the console I have Started GET "/js/vendor/foundation.min.js" for.... No route matches [GET] Same thing for zepto.js

Comment: Seems ok now ! I simply add the line : //= require foundation. Thanks claptimes

Comment: You're welcome. I revised my answer for the foundation line. Can you confirm that's what worked for you?

Comment: NB : I wrote //= require foundation instead of //= foundation